# Neo4j Cypher chain output from match query to APOC

Tags: neo4j, cypher, neo4j-apoc

I wanted to make use of the Neo4j Cypher `apoc.index.search` procedure. I am currently using the Neo4j CE 3.1.0. I have successfully set up and tested the procedure as a stand-alone query such as:

```
call apoc.index.search("Contact2", "Contact2.FirstName:monica~")
```

Now, I want to do a `MATCH` query first to fetch a set of nodes, and spool the `FirstNames` found into calling this APOC procedure on `Contact2` node to see if I can find any similar in the `Contact2` node and the corresponding weight.

Is that possible? I have tried several iterations using the `WITH` keyword but to no avail. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add each `firstName` value as separate fuzzy search terms to the query string passed to `apoc.index.search`. For example:

```
MATCH (f:Foo)
WITH REDUCE(
    s = 'Contact2.FirstName:', n IN COLLECT(DISTINCT f.firstName) |
    s + n + '~ '
  ) AS query
CALL apoc.index.search("Contact2", query)
...
```

Comment: I have tested your code and works great. I agree with your comment made below, yours will generate a very long query string and may not work in a large database. In regards to checking for only FirstName, this is only a test script to confirm the apoc procedure. I will make adjustments to make the query string data more unique - but will take note of your `WITH DISTINCT` statement. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

@cybersam thank you for your answer. I did not try yours but I also just solved this on my own (after days of trying). My syntax is as follows:

// Contact1 is my source table. Contact2 is my destination table

```
MATCH (a:Contact1) WITH a.FirstName AS A 
CALL apoc.index.search("Contact2", "Contact2.FirstName:" + A + "~") 
YIELD node, weight RETURN *
```

I am not sure if that is the best way but it worked for me

Comment: Your approach makes `N` calls to `apoc.index.search` (where `N` is the number of FirstName values), which will be slower than making a single call (which is what my query does -- although my query could end up with an extremely long query string that might cause problems). Also, your query should use `WITH DISTINCT a.FirstName AS A`, since presumably many people can have the same first name and there is no reason to perform the same search multiple times.